# Magento 2 - How to disable a specific area within a Magento 2 Module?

Tags: magento2

I have come through an interesting point while reading the Magento 2 official dev docs.

**You can enable or disable an area within a module.**

Below is the official link of devdocs article,

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_and_areas.html

There it's mentioned. Let's assume if we have adminhtml and frontend area within a module in Magento 2, then how could we disable a particular area?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Magento does it out of the box you can achieve this by `etc/adminhtml/di.xml` for adminhtml same way for frontend.

Reference URL:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/174392)

Comment: @MohitKumarArora I have clearly mentioned that it can be achieved by etc/adminhtml/di.xml & etc/frontend/di.xml you can manage & link is for reference how we can use di.xml